# IIS6 - Classic ASP - Comma to point

Tags: iis-6, asp

There are some classic asp pages we are serving, which require a float to be like 1.5 instead of 1,5. So the comma should be a point.

Any ideas?
Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure, but this seems more of a programming issue and probably belongs on stackoverflow.

But it may be possible the script is using the system settings and you just need to change your [Regional and Language Options](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/307938).